# hibernate - saving entity with an entity in it (that already exists in the db)

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

for simplicity, here is my simplified model:

I got 2 entities:

```
@entity
public class Student {
int id;
School school
...
}
```

and the school is an entity as well

```
@entity
public class School {
int id;
...
}
```

im trying to pull a lot of data from a text file.
some students have the same school instance,
i wouldn't like multiple schools in my database with the same name,
so my goal is to save each student in the student db , while making sure that 2 different students with the same school , wont create 2 entries in my school db.

problem is when i try to persist the students, it gives me an error: 
"detached entity passed to persist" , how do i tell hibernate, that the school in the student class is already exists in the database , and that it should use it instead?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map it with `@ManyToOne(cascade=ALL)`.

"the same name" would not suffice though, you should have the same ID. For that to work, you'd need to make sure your `School` object is taken from the DB before setting it to the Student

Answer (score 0):

There is a method on the session called merge().  Use that instead of saveOrUpdate();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming associations are already set:

Make sure you are working with the persisted Student entity. Do a search for the student entity, and set the school -> student to the student entity returned from the search.

entity.find ( Student.class, student_id)

Otherwise, make sure the associations are annotated before doing the above.